# Android Custom Tile Map

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I'm working on a project that requires a custom tile map of a building to be displayed along with up to several hundred "points" to be plotted as objects within the building, all on one or more mobile platforms (Android to start).

There were two ways I thought of to tackle this issue. One was to use osmdroid or mapsforge to display a zoom-able tile map. One issue I've had with this, however, is that I haven't been able to locate the software to automatically split up the single image into the correct tile format. MapTiler has worked fairly well, except my Y axis tiles are all upside down.

The second was to display the entire image as an imageview, and then write the code to display the points of interest on the map as the image view is scrolled around. However, I'm not quite sure how I would go about drawing an undefined amount of images on top of an image already displayed in an image view.

Does anyone have any ideas or might they be able to point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Have you thought about using the Google Maps JS API (V3).  It'd be easy to work with the markers and custom tiles.

Comment: OSMdroid will work _in principle_, but you'll need high zoom levels to resolve things on a building, and there are [some issues there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273561/osmdroid-pathoverlay-drawing-is-corrupted-at-high-zoom-levels/). I'm going to need to do this too at some point. MapTiler looks interesting; I was originally going to try and do everything using [ImageMagick cropping](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile)  and some scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://code.google.com/p/gheat/ and put the tiles from your server in your android app.